# How to create several winforms, each one in a different process?

Tags: c#, vb.net, winforms

I'm creating a winform application that should behave like Google Chrome.

In chrome for example, it's possible to have multiple windows but each window behaves like a separate application. Means that if you have three windows opened, in Windows Task Manager, you will find three processes.

Does anyone know how to create different windows for the same application but each window is running in a different process ?

I tried to create sevel windows, each of them is in a different threads, but I still have one process.

Thanks.

Comment: First things first; it seems your understanding of what is a thread and what is a process isn't quite right... read http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197182/windows-forms-application-like-google-chrome-with-multiple-processes and http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18702/Threading-in-NET-and-WinForms this is also an interesting well written article on multi threading in winforms http://visualstudiomagazine.com/articles/2010/11/18/multithreading-in-winforms.aspx oh and this http://wyday.com/blog/2010/multi-process-c-sharp-application-like-google-chrome-using-named-pipes/

Comment: @ASh's answer below is spot-on.  If you want different processes, you have to spin up different processes (which means using `Process.Start` or equivalent).

Comment: The term you are going to want to type into the Google search box is "Inter-Process Communication", commonly known as IPC.

Comment: Application needs to Process.Start itself, then IPC like there's no tomorrow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the others already said, you'll have to start your application several times and implement interprocess communication.
You can use PipeStream and Client for this:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.io.pipes.pipestream(v=vs.110).aspx